# Initial carousel setup with materialize

Tags: carousel, materialize

So this is likely a pretty dumb question but this is probably the third carousel I've tried to setup and it's been years since I've done any web work and I'm missing something as it doesn't work and I hope someone can easily point out why.

I've got the materialize.min.js in my js folder and same with css in the css folder. The site is simply loading and stacking all of the images on top of each other but they aren't displayed and none of the functionality is there.

So what am I messing up? Thanks a bunch for any input. (For anybody curious I'm looking to make a vertically aligned navigation that functions in a carousel style you can click on to nav the site)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
            var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
          });

          // Or with jQuery

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.carousel').carousel();
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="placeholder.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="placeholder.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="placeholder.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="placeholder.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="placeholder.jpg"></a>
</div>

<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like the `options` variable you use to call `M.Carousel.init` is not defined. Try calling the function without the second `options` argument.

Comment: That did it, thanks so much Ikkuh!

Answer (score -1):

**js link**

> ```
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
> <script src="https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/pLNzQb"></script>
> ```

**css link**

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/pLNzQb"></script>

 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**html**

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY" class="brand-logo">Materialize Framework</a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY">JavaScript</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


<section id="main-slider">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div><img src="http:placehold.it/1920x480/EF9A9A/fff?text=Owl+Carousels"></div>
    <div><img src="http:placehold.it/1920x480/FFCDD2/EF9A9A?text=Touch+compatible"></div>
    <div><img src="http:placehold.it/1920x480/EF9A9A/fff?text=Images+or+code"></div>
    <div><img src="http:placehold.it/1920x480/FFCDD2/EF9A9A"></div>
</section>





<section id="owl-1">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

      <div class="card hoverable">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
          <img class="activator" src="http://placehold.it/1920/999/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <p><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY/" target="_blank">This is a link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-reveal">
          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="card hoverable">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
          <img class="activator" src="http://placehold.it/1920/888/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <p><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY/" target="_blank">This is a link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-reveal">
          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="card hoverable">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
          <img class="activator" src="http://placehold.it/1920/777/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <p><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY/" target="_blank">This is a link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-reveal">
          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="card hoverable">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
          <img class="activator" src="http://placehold.it/1920/666/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <p><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY/" target="_blank">This is a link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-reveal">
          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="card hoverable">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
          <img class="activator" src="http://placehold.it/1920/555/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <p><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY/" target="_blank">This is a link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-reveal">
          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="card hoverable">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
          <img class="activator" src="http://placehold.it/1920/444/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <p><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY/" target="_blank">This is a link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-reveal">
          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card hoverable">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
          <img class="activator" src="http://placehold.it/1920/333/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <p><a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nbBqgY/" target="_blank">This is a link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-reveal">
          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</section>

<section id="owl-2">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div>
      <img src="http:placehold.it/640x480">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http:placehold.it/640x480/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http:placehold.it/640x480/555/fff">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http:placehold.it/640x480/444/fff">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http:placehold.it/640x480/333/fff">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http:placehold.it/640x480/222/fff">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http:placehold.it/640x480/666/fff">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Gitter Chat Link -->
<div class="fixed-action-btn"><a class="btn-floating btn-large red" href="https://gitter.im/Dogfalo/materialize" target="_blank"><i class="large material-icons">chat</i></a></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {background-color: #eee;}




.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,
  .owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,
  .owl-carousel .owl-dot {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-size: 4rem;
}
.owl-nav {height:0;margin:0;}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev:before{
    // fa-chevron-left
    content: "\E5CB";
    margin-left:16px;
    position: absolute;
      top: 40%;
    left: 0px;
    height: auto;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
                 0px 0px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next:after{
    //fa-chevron-right
    content: "\E5CC";
    margin-right: 16px;
    position: absolute;
      top: 40%;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
                 0px 0px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // OWL CAROUSEL - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/
  $('#main-slider .owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
    {
      items: 1,
      margin: 0,
      loop: true,
      nav: false,
      navText: ['Back','Next'],
      dots: false,
      dotsEach: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 500,
      animateOut: 'fadeOut',
      animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    }
  );
  $('#owl-1 .owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
    {
      items: 4,
      margin: 16,
      loop: true,
      stagePadding: 64,
      nav: true,
      // navText: ['Back','Next'],
      navText: ['',''],
      // navText: ["<img src='myprevimage.png'>","<img src='mynextimage.png'>"],
      dots: false,
      dotsEach: true,
      lazyLoad: false,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 500,
      navSpeed: 500,
      autoplayTimeout: 2000,
      autoplayHoverPause: true,
    }
  );

  $('#owl-2 .owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
    {
      items: 5,
      margin: 16,
      stagePadding: 32,
      loop: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 500,
      navSpeed: 500,
      dots: false,
      dotsEach: true,
      nav: true,
      // navText: ['Back','Next'],
      navText: ['',''],
      autoplayTimeout: 2000,
      autoplayHoverPause: false,
      animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
      animateIn: 'flipInX',
    }
  );

});
```

Comment: The question was about materialize (which has its own carousel) - Why are you using Owl Carousel instead?